# Convert ascii to hex in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex, ascii

I try to convert ascii to hex value. But my script sometimes working, sometimes does not work. I wonder why. Code likes below:

ascii_ch = B13515068

```
for i in range(50):  #In excel I have 50 row
    ascii_ch = sheet['C%s'%(i+2)].value  #after C2, convert hex
    ascii_to_hex= "".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in ascii_ch )
    sheet['I%s'%(i+2)] = ascii_to_hex
    wb.save('a.xlsx')
```

I want to ascii_to_hex= 423133353135303638

Sometimes code works properly, but Generally I get an error like below;
[image]

Comment: Read the error message?

Comment: I shared error message at the end of line ; 
    ascii_to_hex= "".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in ascii_ch )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Um, yeah, I know. But looks like you didn't read it.

Comment: Interesting is that the code sometimes works, sometimes it gives an error.

Comment: That's not interesting at all.

Comment: But I did not change anything, just try to run again and it works

Comment: You ran it with the exact same input data?

Comment: Yes, everything is same

Comment: Hard to imagine. Anyway, then you should figure out why you sometimes get None and sometimes don't. And it doesn't look like that has anything to do with the code you've shown here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like not all cells actually have values associated with them. When a cell has no value, `ascii_ch = sheet['C%s'%(i+2)].value` will set `ascii_ch` to `None`. In the next line, you iterate over `ascii_ch`. But it does not make any sense to iterate over `None`!

You probably want to check for that, like this:

```
for i in range(50):  #In excel I have 50 row
    ascii_ch = sheet['C%s'%(i+2)].value  #after C2, convert hex
    if ascii_ch is None:
        # Maybe warn the user that a value is missing?
        continue  # go on to the next cell
```